# Should DraftJS fire a dispatch in Redux for every editor change?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, draftjs

I'm building a simple Markdown editor and I'm currently saving the EditorState as well as the contents of the document to my store (because I want to be able to persist the document the user is editing). The question I'm facing now is wether the editor state should be handled by Redux or by DraftJS.

Should I delegate the editor changes to Redux or to DraftJS?

Comment: if you use redux, then yes. but you are free to not use redux.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! I think I'm gonna go with Redux handling the state